# on page creation few inline style properties gets removed

Tags: pages

For a website I am not a super admin but I have admin role. The problem is even after being an admin, when I create a page few style properties get vanished. In contrast, when a super admin creates the same page no properties get vanished. Is there any one having the same experience or any idea how to deal with it.

style property like:

```
background-image: url(http://www.imagepath.com);
```

This makes the whole inline style of that element disappear.

Comment: Is it just the style or anything else that you are using like JavaScript? Can you check if the styles are loaded based on an user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought the language is a bit confusing, if you check the Codex and pay attention to the difference between the Admin and the Super Admin you should be able to see what is happening.

> In the case of single site WordPress installation, Administrators are,
>   in effect, Super Admins. As such, they are the only ones to have
>   access to additional admin capabilities.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Super_Admin

And...

> Only Administrators of single site installations have the following
>   capabilities. In Multisite, only the Super Admin has these abilities:
>
> - update_core
> - update_plugins
> - update_themes
> - install_plugins
> - install_themes
> - delete_themes
> - edit_plugins
> - edit_themes
> - edit_users
> - create_users
> - delete_users
> - unfiltered_html
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Additional_Admin_Capabilities

That last capability is the issue.

> unfiltered_html
>
> - Since 2.0
> - Allows user to post HTML markup or even JavaScript code in pages, posts, comments and widgets.
> - Note: Enabling this option for untrusted users may result in their posting malicious or poorly formatted code.
> - Note: In WordPress Multisite, only Super Admins have the unfiltered_html capability.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html

Only Super Admins have the capability you want, and you are an admin. Unless you have access to the site's code to add that capability to the ordinary blog Admins, or just to your particular user, you won't have `unfiltered_html` capability.